# Error "Only support send transaction with ipc" when create a transaction in TomoChain node

Tags: blockchain, tomochain

I've faced some problem when try to work with TOMO block chain. but i can't send message to this channel

I'm using web3 python to working with Tomo testnet rpc. When creating transaction i got this error

ValueError: {'code': -32600, 'message': 'Only support send transaction with ipc'}

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem in NodeJS when using old version web3. I upgrade web3 to version 1.3.1 and solved it